# Deleting element and changing element property in an Array of objects

Tags: javascript

So there is an array of object called employees that has employee's credentials.
I am supposed to delete the object if the employee's name is Theo, and if the employee's name is Lorie I should change the department's property to 'HR'
I've tried using a for loop to go through the objects in the array and change their properties. but it would not return the iterated array.
maybe I need to use the .reduce() method
[Here is the code I've tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B93g8.png)

[image]

Comment: please add the code itself to the post.

Answer (score 0):

It should be working!

Your array of objects.

```
var employees = [
 {
  "firstName": 'Von',
  "lastName": 'budibent',
  "email": "email@mail.com",
  "departement": "Sales"
 },
 {
  "firstName": 'Theo',
  "lastName": 'Trill',
  "email": "email@mail.com",
  "departement": "Services"
 },
 {
  "firstName": 'Lorie',
  "lastName": 'Trill',
  "email": "email@mail.com",
  "departement": "Research and Development"
 }
];
```

Then you need to filter by `firstName` and then mapping the data.

```
var adjustedEmployees = employees
 .filter(employee => employee.firstName !== 'Theo')
 .map((employee) => {
   if (employee.firstName === 'Lorie') employee.departement = 'HR';
   return employee;
 });
```

Comment: or do both on the same filter `var adjustedEmployees = employees.filter(e => e.firstName
  !== 'Theo' && (e.departement = e.firstName === "Lorie" ?
  "HR" : e.departement));`

Comment: Yes, you can do that

Answer (score 0):

//I needed to use a function with no parameters, I figured out how to do it.

[Solved question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCk4x.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Remove employe with firstname 'Theo'
var result = employees.filter(employee => employee.firstName !== 'Theo');
//Change department of Lorie to 'HR'
result.forEach(el => {
  el.departement = el.firstName === 'Lorie' ? 'HR' : el.departement
})
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ok I will do that